# trying to stop duplicate entry for widget ids for users that have already added widget id

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there am coding a small check function that will check a mysql database for a user_id and a widget_id and if the widget id is found to be in table that matchs the user id then it would not let the person add that widget agen the issue i have is soon as one widget is added to database it will not let me add any more for that user_id table would look like this

```
widget_id  user_id
1          12
5          12
6          10
9          2
1          2
1          10
```

so if a user adds same widget as a other user it will allow it but if that user say user (10) tries to re-add widget (1) it would disallow it but if user (10) selects widget (9) it would allow it

```
  public function check_u_widgets($user_id, $widget_id)
  {
    global $db, $system;
    $result = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM users_widgets WHERE user_id = %s", secure($user_id) )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $wid = $result->fetch_assoc();
      if($wid['widget_id'] == $widget_id) {
        throw new Exception(__("Sorry, It seem's that this widget is already assigned"));
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

any one got any ideas on how to sort this thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for both conditions (`AND`) and if found then don't allow.

```php
<?php

function check_u_widgets($user_id, $widget_id)
{
    global $db, $system;
    $result = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM users_widgets WHERE user_id = %s AND widget_id = %s", secure($user_id), secure($widget_id))) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        throw new Exception(__("Sorry, It seem's that this widget is already assigned")); // to this user
    }
    return false;
}
```